# OpenStreetMap and Python recursively find all the bus routes in a city

Tags: python, openstreetmap, route, overpass-api

I want to retrieve all the bus routes (as a collection of lines) from openstreetmap for a given city.

I'm currently using the `overpy` module (v0.4) to access the Overpass API and this query:

```
QUERY = """
[out:json];
area[name="%(city)s"]->.a;
(
  node["route"="%(type)s"](area.a);
  way["route"="%(type)s"](area.a);
  relation["route"="%(type)s"](area.a);
);
out body;
>;
out skel;
"""
```

where `city` is the city i'm interested in, and `type` could either be `bus` or `tram`.

The problem is, this does not work often :( If I'm looking for the bus routes for a very well known city like *Chicago* it returns an empty set, while other times the result set is partial (like for *Philadelphia* for example); very rarely it is able to correctly select the city and grab all the routes.

If I use the same query (without the `area` selector) in http://overpass-turbo.eu/ when focused on *Chicago* it is able to return the routes as expected; so I suspect there's something wrong with the way I'm using `area`

Do you have any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe just try a bounding box search for whatever you consider the city extent to be?

Comment: Your query works fine for Chicago: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/q46. However you can omit searching for nodes and ways, they are never tagged with route=bus (otherwise it is a tagging error). Maybe you are hitting some quota? For example too many parallel requests. Check the HTTP status code

Comment: @BradHards i want to do this programmatically, so i dont want to have to find the bbox of that city by hand: do you know of a way to do that automatically?

Comment: @scai yes i know that query works when entered in overpass-turbo (i even mentioned it in the OP, but thanks for checking it) i dont think there's any quota issue here, as running it for NYC it will return something